# Javascript Object traversal with String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to traverse a JavaScript object with a stored string.

Sample string

```
var x = "Desserts"
```

Sample Object

```
  {
    "dataset":
      { 
      "Categories" : 
               [
                {
                 "Desserts" : 
                   [
                    "Sweets","Ice Creams","Pastry"
                   ]
                } ,
                {
                  "Juices and Beverages" :
                   [
                    "Cold","Hot","Fresh","Sodas"
                   ]
                }
         }
   }
```

If I traverse the object as `dataset.Categories.x`, it doesn't work[returns undefined] . How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried dataset.Categories[0][x]??

Comment: `dataset.Categories[0][x]` , there is an array inside

Comment: @PranavCBalan Sorry. I changed the question. I missed it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `dataset.Categories[0][x]` instead of `dataset.Categories[0].x`

Take a look at :  [dot notation or the bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```js
var x = "Desserts",
  data = {
    "dataset": {
      "Categories": [{
        "Desserts": ["Sweets", "Ice Creams", "Pastry"]
      }, {
        "Juices and Beverages": ["Cold", "Hot", "Fresh", "Sodas"]
      }]
    }

  }

alert(data.dataset.Categories[0][x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    "dataset": {
        "Categories": [{
            "Desserts": ["Sweets", "Ice Creams", "Pastry"]
        }, {
            "Juices and Beverages": ["Cold", "Hot", "Fresh", "Sodas"]
        }]
    }
}


var x = 'Desserts';
var val = obj.dataset.Categories[0][x];
console.log(val);
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/xhr1uj12/).